# Independence property of sub problems for dynamic programming techniques to apply

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming

Two criteria for an algorithm to be solved by dynamic programming technique  is

1. Sub problems should be independent.
2. Sub problems should overlap .

I think I understand what overlapping means . It basically means that the subproblems have subsubproblems that may be the same . So instead of solving the subsubproblem over and over again we solve it once, put it in a hashtable or array and can look it up the nest time it is required . But what does point 1 ie **independence of subproblems** mean here ? If they have some common subsubproblems how can we call them to be independent? I mean it sounds very much counterintuitive to me at this stage .

**Edit**: This crtiteria is actually [given in the famous book: Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS in the Dynamic Programming chapter.](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/)

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us where you are reading that DP applies to problems with overlapping and independent sub-problems.  I don't think that's correct, for the same intuitive reason you give-- if the problems overlap, they aren't independent.

I usually see independent sub-problems given as a criterion for Divide-And-Conquer style algorithms, while I see overlapping sub-problems and *optimal sub-structure* given as criteria for the Dynamic Programming family.  (Intuitively, optimal substructure means that the best solution of a larger problem is composed of the best solutions of sub-problems.  The classic example is the shortest path in a graph problem:  If you know that the shortest path from A to B goes through C, then you also know that *the part of* the shortest path from A to B that goes through C happens to be the shortest path from A to C.)

**UPDATE:** Oh, I see-- yes, I guess they do mention independence.  But I don't read that with the same emphasis that you are.  Meaning, they mention independence in the context of, or as a way of understanding, the larger and more important concept of optimal substructure.

What they mean specifically by independence is that even if two problems overlap, they are "independent" in the sense that they don't interact-- the solution to one does not really depend on the solution to the other.  They actually use the same example I did, the shortest path.  Sub-problems of the shortest path problem are smaller shortest path problems that are independent:  If the shortest path from A to B goes through C, then the shortest path from A to C doesn't use any edges in the shortest path from C to B.  The *longest path* problem, by contrast, does not share that independence of sub-problems.

I don't think CLRS are wrong to bring up independence, but I do think the language they're using is a little ambiguous.

Comment: It is given in the book [Introduction to Algorithms (Dynamic programming chapter) by Cormen te al](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/)

Answer (score 1):

As offered in CLRS, the authors address the distinction between independent and overlapping properties of subproblems. They write,

> "It may seem strange that dynamic programming relies on subproblems being both  independent and overlapping. Although these requirements may sound contradictory, they describe two different notions, rather than two points on the same axis. Two subproblems of the same problem are independent if they do not share resources. Two subproblems are overlapping if they are really the same subproblem that occurs as a subproblem of different problems" (CLRS 3rd edition, 386).

Answer (score 0):

I think these criteria have been worded badly because overlapping and independent have sort of a clashing meaning.

Anyway to be able to use effectively a DP approach you need to have

1. a problem that can be defined recursively in terms of simpler problems
2. a concept of partial solution in which the solution to the remaining part does't depend ho how you got to current point

Example: if you want to compute what is the maximum-sum path when moving in a matrix starting from the first row and having each step on next row and in the same or in an adjacent column you can use as "state" the current sum, current row and current column because for the solution it doesn't matter what was the path used to get to the current position.

```
1  4 [3] 2  1  4  9
2  1 [3] 1  2  3  1
9 [8] 3  0  1  2  9
0 [0] 2  4  1  6  3
1  2 [6] 3  0  4  1
```

In the schema above this path has a sum of 3+3+8+0+6. To maximize the sum you can observe that the maximum for paths passing from a certain point can be obtained as the maximum for getting there and the maximum for going from there to the end of the matrix. The solution can therefore be split in independent subproblems and you can cache the result of what is the maximum sum from a given point of the matrix to the end (independently on how you got to the point).

```
def maxsum(x, y):
    if (x, y) in cache:
        return cache[(x, y)]

    if y == height - 1:
        return matrix[y][x]

    if x == 0:
        left = -1
    else:
        left = matrix[y][x] + maxsum(x-1, y+1)

    center = matrix[y][x] + maxsum(x, y+1)

    if x == width-1:
        right = -1
    else:
        right = matrix[y][x] + maxsum(x+1, y+1)

    result = cache[(x, y)] = max(left, center, right)
    return result
```

If I add to the rules that no more than three "9"s are allowed however you cannot use as state just the coordinates, because following subproblem (going to the end) will be influenced by the previous one (i.e. by how many "9" you already collected while getting to the intermediate position).

You can still use a dynamic programming approach, but with a larger state space by for example adding the numbers of collected "9" to the current state representation.

```
def maxsum(x, y, number_of_nines):
    if (x, y, number_of_nines) in cache:
        return cache[(x, y, number_of_nines)]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is sub problem should be solved independent of parent bigger problem. Like in backtracking the subproblem do depend on solutions you picked in bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

The subproblems are independent.

Independence is not there in divide and conquer.
For eg. in mergesort.
The subproblems are merged after dividing which means that the solution has had common subproblems. And everything is needed to be merged and not one path will give an answer.
Every subproblem share sub-subproblem which are needed to be solved in order to get the final answer.

```
                       (1, 4)
                     /         \
             (1, 2)             (3, 4)
          /        \            /       \
      (1,1)         (2,2)  (3,3)          (4,4)
          \          /          \        /
              (1,2)               (3, 4)
                      \         /  
                         (1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think subproblems should be dependent. In fact it would be great if subproblems are independent, but it's not necessary.

A good example for a dp problem with dependent subproblems is here:
[Paint Houses - Algorithmic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45401569/3769451) (paint house problem)

Here, the solution to subproblems depends on the color of the previous house. That dependency can be solved by adding a dimension to the dp array and building the solution based on the color of the previous house.